Flickering problems on external monitor after installing Ubuntu 23.10
I just installed Ubuntu 23.10 on my Thinkpad L13. It works fine on my laptop monitor. But when I connect an HDMI cable to my other monitor, the screen flickers on the laptop and nothing shows on the other monitor.
I know it can't be a problem with the other monitor as I bought it brand new last week, and the cable works fine on this same laptop when I run in Windows, and it works fine on other laptops with Windows/macOS.
I already installed the driver with sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-dkms-535 and rebooted, but that didn't help.
This laptop uses an Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2.
I also tried editing etc/default/grub by adding nomodeset or radeon.modeset=0 within the quotation marks in the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT but that didn't help either.
Can anyone help?

are you using X11 or Wayland windowing system? ISTR an issue with Wayland and nvidia - perhaps try it with X11 and [edit] your question accordingly.

I think it was using Wayland because echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE showed wayland. But even when I rebooted and selected ubuntu on xorg and echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE now shows x11, I still get the flickering problem
